# Why Wordpres custom HTML block is changing my code?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using the "Geolocation IP Detection" plugin in order to provide visitors with localized Amazon Affiliate links.

When I enter something like this in my Custom HTML blocks:

```
[geoip_detect2_show_if country="MX"]
<div class="wp-block-buttons is-content-justification-center">
 <!--wp:button {"backgroundColor":"luminous-vivid- 
  orange","textColor":"white","className":"is-style-fill"} -->
 <div class="wp-block-button is-style-fill">
  <a class="wp-block-button__link has-white-color has-luminous- 
    vivid-orange-background-color has-text-color has-background" href="https://amzn.to/example" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener nofollow">See on Amazon</a>
 </div>
 <!-- /wp:button -->
</div>
[/geoip_detect2_show_if]
```

I get this in my custom HTML blocks when I come back to the editor:

```
[geoip_detect2_show_if country="MX"]
<div class="wp-block-buttons is-content-justification-center"></div>
[/geoip_detect2_show_if]
```

The links are removed in the editor. The blocks seems to work correctly (providing the localized links), but if I save the page again, the code without the links gets updated into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the gutenberg editor.
Try building the layout by using the dedicated shortcode blocks before and after your custom html block.
So [geoip_detect2_show_if country="MX"] in the top shortcode block, your custom html as you have it in the custom html block (remove the commented items if you don't need them) followed by [/geoip_detect2_show_if] in a shortcode block afterwards.